# Find current viewController to push a ABPersonViewController in Titanium Mobile

Tags: iphone, titanium, abpeoplepickerview

in an application I'm working on, I need to interact with iPhone's AddressBook.

Currently, Titanium mobile doesn't expose the native widget so I decided to write a module to trying to overcome this limitation.

As far as I know, the only way to change a navigationControl is through showModalController

```
[[TiApp app] showModalController:picker animated:animated];
```

which adds a modal controller to current view, but it's useless for my app, because it's tabbed.
What I need is a way to push my viewController onto the current one, embedded in current tab.

Is there any *clean* way to reach this result?

That feature is a show stopper, so if I don't find a way soon, I've to switch to native implementation :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Titanium will show the native contact picker (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController) with the`Ti.Contacts.showContacts` method ([doc](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Contacts.showContacts-method.html)).

Also, you should be able to use `showModalController:animated:` with a tabbed view. The modal view will cover the tabs until dismissed, but that's how modal views work on the iPhone.